# what is source rectangle in spritebatch.draw in xna

Tags: xna

What is the purpose of the source rectangle parameter in the SpriteBatch.Draw() method?

MSDN says: `A rectangle that specifies (in texels) the source texels from a texture. Use null to draw the entire texture.`

What does that mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The idea of the `sourceRectangle` is to allow you to implement what is both a performance optimisation and an artist convenience by arranging multiple **sprites** into a single **texture**. This is known as a "Texture Atlas" or a "Sprite Sheet".

[image]
<sub>(source: [andrewrussell.net](http://andrewrussell.net/content/2010/12/Sprite-Sheet-Example.png))</sub>

[I explain why it is a performance optimisation in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/optimizing-an-xna-2d-game/9289#9289). Basically it lets you reduce the number of texture-swaps. (So in the case of my illustration, if you're only drawing an animated character once, using a sprite-sheet will not improve performance.)

It also lets you implement tacky 2D special effects, like having a sprite "wipe" in:

[image]
<sub>(source: [andrewrussell.net](http://andrewrussell.net/content/2010/12/Reveal-Animation-Example.png))</sub>

A `texel` is more-or-less the same thing as a pixel in the texture (a "texture pixel", if you will). So, when you draw your sprite, you specify the top-left corner of your **sprite** within the **texture**, along with its width and height. (The same as if you selected it in an image editor.)

If you pass in `null` for your source rectangle, XNA will assume a source rectangle that covers the entire texture.

The `origin` you specify to `Draw` is also measured in texels from the upper-left corner of the source rectangle.

Comment: _"So in the case of my illustration, if you're only drawing an animated character once, using a sprite-sheet will not improve performance."_ Won't using a spritesheet potentially improve RAM usage and disk space?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Not RAM usage or disk space (by any significant amount). However you do remind me of an interesting point that I didn't mention: It is much faster to load a single large file **from disk** than it is to load many small files. (There are lots of ways to pack assets into a single file - a sprite sheet is a pretty simple one.) Just remember that the improvement is load-time, not run-time. Like most performance optimisations, you should only worry about it once you can measure that the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation where you have a single texture that contains different frames (animated textures), you will want to specify the source rectangle, so that you can draw a single frame from a texture.

i.e.
Look at this spritesheet [here](http://www.google.co.za/imgres?imgurl=http://userpedia.adriels.com/wiki/images/7/7d/Flame-O_sprite_sheet.PNG&imgrefurl=http://userpedia.adriels.com/wiki/Sprites&usg=__LDwjNusnTyD1UAwCnUC2tdu7AyE=&h=841&w=818&sz=72&hl=en&start=0&sig2=d0YtEF4iS7Hc5N6w77O4XA&zoom=1&tbnid=e_xuz3J3ecUfgM%3a&tbnh=181&tbnw=176&ei=AXNwTe2aA8b5sgadmfjxBw&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dspritesheet%26um%3D1%26hl%3Den%26sa%3DN%26biw%3D1440%26bih%3D799%26tbs%3Disch:1&um=1&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=318&vpy=412&dur=797&hovh=228&hovw=221&tx=164&ty=121&oei=AXNwTe2aA8b5sgadmfjxBw&page=1&ndsp=29&ved=1t:429,r:15,s:0)

Answer (score 0):

The source rectangle defines the area of the texture that will be displayed. So if you have a 40x40 texture, and your rectangle is (0, 0, 20, 20), only the top left corner of the texture will be displayed. If you specify null for the rectangle, you will draw the entire texture.

This can be helpful when drawing from a spritesheet (a collection of textures that are all put into one bigger texture), and also in image manipulation programs.