# In XNA , what's the difference between the rectangle width and the texture's width in a sprite?

Tags: xna, textures, sprite, xna-4.0, rectangles

Let's say you did this: `spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, myRectangle, Color.White);`

And you have this:

```
myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("myCharacterTransparent");
myRectangle = new Rectangle(10, 100, 30, 50);
```

Ok, so now we have a rectangle width of 30. Let's say the myTexture's width is 100.

So with the first line, does it make the sprite's width 30 because that's the width you set to the rectangle,  while the `myTexture` width stays 100? Or does the sprite's width go 100 because that's the width of the texture?

Comment: Just try it! ^^ When you have doubts with any 3D framework, just try all the possibilities at once (ex: texture > rectangle, texture < rectangle and texture = rectangle).

Comment: I did try but i'm seriously confused. I guess what I really need to know is what does the rectangle actually do and what effect does the texture have on the sprite.

Comment: Your question was already answered  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189833/what-is-source-rectangle-in-spritebatch-draw-in-xna

Answer (score 0):

the Rectangles used by the Draw-method defines what part of the Texture2D should be drawn in what part of the rendertarget (usually the screen).

This is how we use tilesets, for instance;

```
class Tile
{
    int Index;
    Vector2 Position;
}

Texture2D tileset = Content.Load<Texture2D>("sometiles"); //128x128 of 32x32-sized tiles
Rectangle source = new Rectangle(0,0,32,32); //We set the dimensions here.
Rectangle destination = new Rectangle(0,0,32,32); //We set the dimensions here.
List<Tile> myLevel = LoadLevel("level1");

//the tileset is 4x4 tiles

in Draw:
spriteBatch.Begin();
foreach (var tile in myLevel)
{
    source.Y = (int)((tile.Index / 4) * 32);
    source.X = (tile.Index - source.Y) * 32;

    destination.X = (int)tile.Position.X;
    destination.Y = (int)tile.Position.Y;

    spriteBatch.Draw(tileset, source, destination, Color.White);
}
spriteBatch.End();
```

I may have mixed up the order of which the rectangles are used in the draw-method, as I am doing this off the top of my head while at work.

Edit; Using only Source Rectangle lets you draw only a piece of a texture on a position of the screen, while using only destination lets you scale the texture to fit wherever you want it.