# XNA game studio simple sprite animation

Tags: xna-4.0

Ok so im writing 2d game like bubble-bobble i have sprites i have done the physics (moving,jumping,falling so far :D) i have done some kind of shooting but now i want to make my player sprite(rectangle image) animated,but i dont want some kind of very complicated animation. I want something like this : i have 2 player images Right faced creature and Left faced creature the rectangle size of the images is exactly the same ,i also have :

`Vector2 playerPosition` declared

`player = Content.Load<Texture2D>("PlayerRight");` in my `LoadContent`

`spriteBatch.Draw(player, playerPosition, Color.White);` in my draw function

all i want is when i press Right/Left - arrow buttons my player image switch between 
Right/Left faced images

i dont know what kind of code and where i have to write for that task.
if you need more information about the task please let me know

Answer (score 0):

this is not best solution, but it could give you hint.

```
playerRight = Content.Load<Texture2D>("PlayerRight");
playerLeft = Content.Load<Texture2D>("PlayerLeft");
playerCameraFacing = Content.Load<Texture2D>("playerCameraFacing");
```

declare PlayerSprite as Texture2D in player class

update funciton pseudo:

```
PlayerSprite = playerCameraFacing ;
if key.left then PlayerSprite = playerLeft;
if key.right then PlayerSprite = playerRight;
```

draw function pseudo:

```
draw(PlayerSprite, Position, Color)
```

i put all my animation frames into single image, and then show them using "sourceRectangle".
[what is source rectangle in spritebatch.draw in xna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189833/what-is-source-rectangle-in-spritebatch-draw-in-xna)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx